# Get data from a multidimensional array, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have an array, [here is an example](https://jsonblob.com/7bc702c3-78cd-11ea-8599-b13d8aa05ba9) , and I want to get all data from (content && children). But in children I can have another (content && children) ,and so on.. If I use foreach ,I can get data just from level 1 or 2  (I don't want to use to many), so I don't get data from last level. I tried to use  `array_walk_recursive` , but I don't get the correct data.
The data from the link is from `json_encode($fulljson)`

```
    public function array_rec($item, $key)
    {
        return "$key holds $item\n";
    }
   public function handlerData(){
        Log::info('Test:' . array_walk_recursive($fulljson, 'self::array_rec'));
   }

//output will be Test: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[`data_get`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-data-get) can get you data from a nested array if you know its structure.

> ```php
> $data = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];
>
> $price = data_get($data, 'products.desk.price');
>
> // 100
> ```