# Print Value from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, for-loop

I am doing project in Laravel.
Given below is my output array

> Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object (
> [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [u_id] =>
> f2772366-4e7f-4257-90bd-8ea506dd8f84 ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHrCt.png) => stdClass Object ( [u_id]
> => c0b6da0f-1268-4c0d-a38c-675cc33573a8 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [u_id] => 15a31589-bba6-4e22-a5c2-1dcd13f43cfe ) [3] => stdClass
> Object ( [u_id] => a4a05a47-edfe-4f00-aeca-4607897ec760 ) [4] =>
> stdClass Object ( [u_id] => f8b20d31-ac80-4a98-b561-d255c79236fd ) [5]
> => stdClass Object ( [u_id] => 3901ee9e-01bb-483a-9f74-8f7b76290cd5 ) ) [escapeWhenCastingToString:protected] => ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHrCt.png) =>
> Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array (
> [0] => stdClass Object ( [u_id] =>
> 15a31589-bba6-4e22-a5c2-1dcd13f43cfe ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHrCt.png) => stdClass Object ( [u_id]
> => 3901ee9e-01bb-483a-9f74-8f7b76290cd5 ) ) [escapeWhenCastingToString:protected] => ) )

I need to print u_id separated by comma

This is what I have done. showing error

```
foreach($selectedUsers as $key => $selectedUser){
            $listUser[] = $selectedUser->u_id;
        }
```

On dd() output like this[image]

Comment: and what error is it showing? $selectedUser itself seems to be an array. have you tried printing $selectedUser and see what is returned? We need more info if we are to help you.

Comment: @Mashtan Property [u_id] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Related: [How can I fetch the nested relation through a single statement into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69461155/2943403) and [Get data from a multidimensional array, Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61080458/2943403)

Comment: Please never present textual data as an image. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2943403)

Comment: based on dd output image you should try `$flaten_arr = Arr::flatten($listUser);
        $result = Arr::join($flaten_arr, ',');`

Answer (score 0):

After

```
foreach($selectedUsers as $key => $selectedUser){
        $listUser[] = $selectedUser->u_id;
    }
```

this foreach, you had an array in the`$listUser` variable. You can use `implode()` function to merge them with commas. For eg:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$temp = implode(",", $arr);
echo $temp;
```

which will give a string `a,b,c`
you can see mode details about `implode` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)

Comment: The asker already stated in their question that `foreach($selectedUsers as $key => $selectedUser){ $listUser[] = $selectedUser->u_id; }` is "showing error".  This means that your answer cannot possibly work.